# Does the radius of convergence always exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Does the radius of convergence always exist?

For $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-c)^n,$ my textbook states that the radius of convergence is $R=1/\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. However, what if this limit doesn't exist? Does this imply there is no radius of convergence?

Comment: $\limsup$ always ''exists''. You can get $\infty$ but then use $1/\infty=0$.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you @sigmabe